# display one to many users using socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, peerjs

hey guys am trying to make a wrtc video conference of one to many, using socket.io nodejs react and peerjs, well so far its working but all the users are seeing each other, i want all the users to see only the person who started the connection but the person who started the connection can see everyone please help i don't know how to fix this.

for now for each video stream it creats a video element and set the srcObt to the stream but i want the users connected to get only the stream of the user who started and the user who started the connection can get all the streams of the users connected.

**myNode/socket code**

```
io.on('connection',socket =>{
  socket.on('join-class',(classId,palsid)=>{
      socket.join(classId)
      socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-connected',palsid)
      
      socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
          socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnect',palsid)
      })
  })
  
})

server.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('server is running on port 4000')
})
```

**my frontend code using react**

```
import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import Peer from 'peerjs'
import './ClassWall.css'
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';
import img from '../../uploads/349-3498013_laptop-personal-computer-diagram-computer-icons-download-laptop-clipart.png'

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/')


class LiveClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            userId :'',
            classStatus: '',
            videoSrc:'',
            visible: false
        }
    } 
    
    async componentDidMount(){
                
        //set the user id of logedin user
        const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
        const Myvideo = document.createElement('video')
        Myvideo.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            console.log(Myvideo)
        })
        Myvideo.muted = true

        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/Auth//UserID/id',{
                headers:{token:localStorage.token}
            })
            const Parse = await response.json()
            this.setState({userId:Parse})
        } catch (error) {
                        
        }
        //get user id to connect through peer
        const myPeer = new Peer(this.state.userId,{
            host: '/',
            port:4001
        })
        //connect and share video stream
        try {
            const peers = {}
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video:true,
                audio:true
            }).then(stream =>{
            addVideoStream(Myvideo,stream)
            
                myPeer.on('call',call=>{
                    call.answer(stream)
                    const video = document.createElement('video')
                    call.on('stream',userVideostream=>{
                        addVideoStream(video,userVideostream)
                    })
                })
            
                socket.on('user-connected',userId=>{
                    connectToNewUser(userId,stream)
                  console.log('newUser',userId)
                })
            })
            
            socket.on('user-disconnect', userId=>{
                if(peers[userId])peers[userId].close()
            })
            
            myPeer.on('open',id=>{
                socket.emit('join-class',this.props.match.params.id,id)
            })
            //get user stream and connect
            function connectToNewUser(userId,stream){
                const call  = myPeer.call(userId,stream)
                const video = document.createElement('video')
                video.setAttribute("class",`pointer`)
                video.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    console.log(video)
                })
                    call.on('stream',userVideostream=>{
                        addVideoStream(video,userVideostream)
                    })
                call.on('close',()=>{
                    video.remove()
                })
            
                peers[userId]=call
            }
            
            //Add video stream
            function addVideoStream(video,stream){
                const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
                video.srcObject = stream
                video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () =>{
                    video.play()
                })
                videoGrid.append(video)
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error',error)    
        }
        this.checkIfClassTrue()   
    }

    //check if its class
    checkIfClassTrue = async()=>{
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/liveclass/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        const Parse = await response.json()
        this.setState({classStatus:Parse})
    }
 
    //modal
    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
          visible: true,
        });
      };
    
      handleOk = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
          visible: false,
        });
      };
    
      handleCancel = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
          visible: false,
        });
      };
    
   
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               {
                   this.state.classStatus === 'Not found'?
                   'not found':
                   <div>
                       
                       <div id="video-grid">
                                {/* <img src={img}/> */}
                            </div>
                            <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
                        Open Modal
                        </Button>
                        <Modal
                        title="Basic Modal"
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        onOk={this.handleOk}
                        onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                        >
                        
                        </Modal>
                   </div>
               }
            </div>
        )
    }
    }

export default LiveClass
```